# str_replace inside foreach loop not replacing

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, preg-match-all

MY CODE :

```
$string = "@admin BLA BLA @mark BLA BLA BLA @koko BLA BLA";    
preg_match_all("/(@\w+)/", $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $usernames) {
    $user = (" SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . $usernames . "' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($user)) {
        $string = str_replace($usernames, $row["userid"], $string);
    }
}
echo $string;
```

I am trying to replace all `usernames` after `@` with their associated user id , but when I print the text, the output is same as the original text.

output :
`@admin BLA BLA @mark BLA BLA BLA @koko BLA BLA`

Comment: I doubt your database contains usernames with `@` prefix. You need to strip that off to get an effect.

Comment: Also, consider using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback) for running an algorithm (in this case, getting the user ID) on matches.

Comment: Are not you replacing all content and save them inside $string? I mean over writing

Comment: `$user` is never executed. Unless there is more code your `mysqli_fetch_array` should be failing. Also if not using the capture group no need to have it `/@\w+/`.

Comment: Have you executed the query?

Comment: @chris85 the query is working , i test it

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't execute the query, is this a shortened version than your actual code?

Comment: @chris85 , sorry i don't understand you .. this query is working with my database as a good but i don't know where is a problem in my code but the problen not in a query

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` does not execute a query. `mysqli_query` does and requires the connection string. I'd use prepared statements as well, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Comment: @chris85 , okay brother i edit my code on the top .. but it is same problem

Comment: Never use `mysql_*`. I meant exactly what I said. `mysqli_fetch_array does not execute a query. mysqli_query does`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php You still need to fetch the result object after that.

Comment: @chris85 , are you sure this problem in a query ? beacouse i used `mysqli_query` and still same problem :(

Comment: Nope, but I know that `fetch_array` on a string will not work. Update the question with your code.

Comment: @chris85 , okay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query will be something like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '@admin'` - which may be not your expectation.

Try this fix:

`$user = (" SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . substr($usernames, 1) . "' ");`

Hope that it can help you :)

Comment: thanks brother , i understand where is the problem ;)